# Visited status broken because of extra URL parameters of `/search` results

Tags: bug

When I search just by tag request, it goes to `/questions/tagged/...`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ktor

[image]

And when I add some parameters like `is:q`, it switches to `/search?...`

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bktor%5d%20is%3aq%20duplicate%3a0%20hasaccepted%3a0%20closed%3a0

[image]

The problem is that all links inside `/search` results have additional URL parameters like `?r=SearchResults&s=1|16.1426`, probably for some stats, and this breaks visited status to me.

I need to see which questions I already checked out.

Comment: Looks like this only applies to _some_ of the results, most of mine highlighted in both correctly, but 1 in 5 did as described.

Comment: It looks like for tracking purposes the url gets an extra query parameter `?r=searchResults` and that makes it a different url from your browsers point of view. Maybe the javascript telemetry doesn't satisfy the ad team anymore and they want hard urls in the logs to confirm you've reached that question from a search result.

Comment: @rene which would be funny since the entire query string is sent with the referer on same origin.

Comment: Worth noting that *visited* is a browser responsibility based on urls in browser cache. Any variation in the url query string will make it a new unique url as far as browser is concerned

Comment: @charlietfl so this only because `?r=SearchResults&s=1|16.1426` appender?

Comment: Yes that makes it unique compared to version without those params  (or same params with different values) in cache

Comment: While I do consider this an issue, it's one which I'd assume isn't going to be quickly fixed by SE (if they don't consider it [meta-tag:status-bydesign]). Thus, it seems like it's something which you will need to solve for your own use via userscript. You could execute something like: `$('.js-search-results .question-hyperlink, .js-search-results .answer-hyperlink').each(function() {const $this = $(this); $this.attr('href', $this.attr('href').replace(/\?[^#]*/, ''));})`.

Comment: @Makyen Here's something like that: `document.querySelectorAll('.js-search-results .question-hyperlink, .js-search-results .answer-hyperlink').forEach(el => el.href = el.href.replace(el.search, ''))`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, that will work (assuming not Firefox < 53), but has the side effect of changing the URL from absolute path (e.g. `/questions/123456`) to absolute (e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123456`). While that's unlikely to be a problem, I was avoiding that in case there was some other script relying on the `href` attribute being an absolute path. Some such hypothetical other script shouldn't be relying upon that, but it might. OTOH, I agree that using the `.search` property of the `HTMLAnchorElement` is better than using a regular expression (ignoring the FF < 53 issue).

Comment: @Makyen Yeah, I'm weaning myself off of jQuery so I just wanted to see if I could do it, hence "something like that" :). I figure SO only supports last two versions so I'm safe from ancient Firefox.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for this script, it works good! But I've noticed, that after I click on a link, which was modified my userscipt, it gets replaced with the original link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo228.gif. Any idea how to prevent it?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Sure, changing the above code to: `$('.js-search-results .question-hyperlink, .js-search-results .answer-hyperlink').each(function() {const $this = $(this); const newHref = $this.attr('href').replace(/\?[^#]*/, ''); $this.attr({href: newHref, 'data-searchsession': newHref});})` should work.

Comment: @Makyen Another problem this script creates is that it stops the inbox and reputation window from loading. Requires 3 clicks to open instead of one: [bug video](https://youtu.be/A7rkdH49FlU), [script code](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/c65c7d590d73ec26d80a0d1d620b5a22), [console error](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/d6aaa85242ddba0eca23bada3c27e44e)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Remove the `@require` of jQuery.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks! It's my first user script, so I don't even remember where this one came from while I was trying to make it work=)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov When and how you *might* want to `@require` jQuery in a userscript is complex and has a variety of gotchas/corner cases/and incompatibilities between different browser, userscript manager, and usage combinations. It's something which is a good idea to avoid, if possible, for multiple reasons, not the least of which is that it's 95kB of minimized JavaScript code which has to be loaded into every page, which doesn't make a lot of sense to do in order to save a few 10's or a couple 100 characters of code in a userscript. There are a variety alternate things that might be done.